# How to prevent reflected XSS using PHP?

Tags: php, xss

I create a web application using PHP, and I try to protect my application against XSS attacks and SQL-Injection. I have a problem with reflected XSS. I used urlencode() function, but I am not sure if that function protects my application against reflected XSS. Someone could say me if that safe ?

```
$id = urlencode($_GET['id']);

$query = $this->database->ConnectDatabase()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user where user_id = :user_id");
$query->bindParam(':user_id',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: To avoid xss, you need context-aware output encoding, not arbitrary storage escaping.

Comment: So can you write which function I should use ?

Comment: No can do. You're still not letting on the relevant context. (How did you come across the term "reflective" XSS, but remain unaware that it's all about output?)

Comment: [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3126072) / [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1996122)

Comment: Your code does not emit any response so there's no chance of any reflected XSS here. And there's nothing you can do when storing data that will pre-emptively prevent future code to generate a vulnerability by misusing such data.